# I need Help for Roboium Methods

Tags: robotium

How to use getAllOpenedActivities(), getActivityMonitor(), setActivityOrientation(),  getButton();  getCurrentButton(), methods? I'am new for Robotium even i dont know how to use any get method, Please anyone help me to explain with example. It'll more helpful for me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use any of the methods, you need to create a `Solo` object. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}
```

Then in your test method you call the method:

```
public void testYourTest() throws IOException{
      solo.clickOnText("Menu"); 
      solo.getButton("Button 1"); 
      etc. 
}
```

I would recommend that you reference the javadoc that Robotium provides. It was included in the file you downloaded as a .jar file. You need to change the extension (.jar) to zip (.zip).

Hope this helps!